# If a character is hit multiple times by a crippling weapon, does the crippling effect stack?

Tags: weapons, warhammer-40k, only-war

My regiment has variant pattern autoguns with the crippling(2) quality. If I shoot an ork once and deal damage and one of my squadmates also hits the ork with his autogun, does the ork take 2 or 4 damage if he does more than a half-action?

Answer (score 2):

According to some of the 40krpg community, [the Crippling effect does not stack, but a higher level Crippling effect will replace a lower level one](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/92269-is-crippling-cumulative/) (i.e. Crippling (1) will be replaced by Crippling (2) on a target hit by one then the other). (The linked forum may be defunct due to FFG losing the rights to the 40k license.)

However, [some do believe that it does/should stack](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/76742-questions-from-a-new-group/) (in a manner equivalent to your own understanding).

And there is [a general rules-question thread which also asks the same question you did and is worth checking out to help better understand which position you would like to take](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/77479-current-rules-issues/).

It is worth noting the threads in question relate to Black Crusade. However, Only War and Black Crusade would appear to have identical text/rules for the Crippling weapon effect, according to the 40krpgtools website. So ideally the difference in system need not be considered for this particular question.

Having combed through a few of the erratas (Black Crusade, Only War, Deathwatch), no mention is made of what interpretation if any is correct. So unfortunately you, your DM, and your group will need to determine which of the interpretations you'd like to follow amongst yourselves.